# Titanfall - Dead mans trigger

Tags: titanfall

In Titanfall, which items constitute "planted explosives" for use with dead man's trigger? For example, the satchel charge doesn't seem to go off upon death- I assumed it would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dead mans trigger works for both Arc Mines and Satchel Charges. After you die any **placed** mine or charge will explode after around 1 second delay.

For example a good use of Dead mans trigger is while playing hardpoint, throw satchels around the hardpoint you are at. If the enemy is able to kill you, you will still mostly likely be able to kill them from the explosions and keep the hardpoint neutral or defended that much longer.

Comment: Surplus Satchels burncard works well dead man's trigger. It gives you an infinite supply of more powerful satchels. Just run around planting satchels charges while you're alive and let all hell break out when you die.

Comment: @Gordon not really. There is still a limit on how many you can have placed.